# Monitoring how thread blocks are allocated to SMs across execution time?

Tags: cuda

I am a beginner with CUDA profiling. I basically want to generate a timeline that shows each SM and the the thread block that was assigned to it across execution time.

Something similar to this:

Author: Sreepathi Pai
[image]

I have read about reading %smid register, but I don't know how to incorporate it with the code that I want to test, or how to relate that to thread blocks or time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full code is beyond the scope of this answer so this answer provides the building blocks for you to implement block trace.

1. Allocate a buffer 16 bytes * number of blocks. This can be done per launch or a larger buffer can be allocated and maintained for multiple launches.
2. Pass the pointer of the block either through a constant variable or as an additional kernel parameter.
3. Modify your **global** functions to accept the parameter and perform the code listed below. I recommend writing new **global** function wrappers and have the wrapper kernel call the old code. This makes it easier to handle kernels with multiple exit points.

Visualizing Data

1. On compute capability 2.x devices the timestamp function should be clock64. This clock is not synchronized across SMs. The recommend approach is to sort the times per SM and use the lowest time per SM as the time of the kernel launch. This will only be off by 100s of cycles from the real time so for reasonable size kernels this drift is negligible.
2. Remove the smid from the lower 4-bits of the first 8 byte value. Clear the lower 4-bits of the end timestamp.

Allocate a device buffer equal to number of blocks * 16 bytes. Each 16 byte records will store the start and end timestamp as well as a 5-bit smid packed into the start time.

```
static __device__ inline uint32_t __smid()
{
    uint32_t smid;
    asm volatile("mov.u32 %0, %%smid;" : "=r"(smid));
    return smid;
}

// use globaltimer for compute capability >= 3.0 (kepler and maxwell)
// use clock64 for compute capability 2.x (fermi)
static __device__ inline uint64_t __timestamp()
{
    uint64_t globaltime;
    asm volatile("mov.u64 %0, %%globaltimer;" : "=l"(globaltime) );
    return globaltime;
}

__global__ blocktime(uint64_t* pBlockTime)
{
    // START TIMESTAMP
    uint64_t startTime = __timestamp();
    // flatBlockIdx should be adjusted to 1D, 2D, and 3D launches to minimize
    // overhead. Reduce to uint32_t if launch index does not exceed 32-bit.
    uint64_t flatBlockIdx = (blockIdx.z * gridDim.x * gridDim.y)
        + (blockIdx.y * gridDim.x)
        + blockIdx.x;

    // reduce this based upon dimensions of block to minimize overhead
    if (threadIdx.x == 0 && theradIdx.y == 0 && threadIdx.z == 0)
    {
        // Put the smid in the 4 lower bits. If the MultiprocessCounter exceeds
        // 16 then increase to 5-bits. The lower 5-bits of globaltimer are
        // junk. If using clock64 and you want the improve precision then use
        // the most significant 4-5 bits.
        uint64_t smid = __smid();
        uint64_t data = (startTime & 0xF) | smid;
        pBlockTime[flatBlockIdx * 2 + 0] = data;
    }

    // do work

    // I would recommend changing your current __global__ function to be
    // a __global__ __device__ function and call it here. This will result
    // in easier handling of kernels that have multiple exit points.

    // END TIMESTAMP
    // All threads in block will write out. This is not very efficient.
    // Depending on the kernel this can be reduced to 1 thread or 1 thread per warp.
    uint64_t endTime = __timestamp();
        pBlockTime[flatBlockIdx * 2 + 1] = endTime;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I have used the code provided, and it does what I want.

Answer (score 1):

```
__noinline__ __device__ uint get_smid(void)
{
    uint ret;
    asm("mov.u32 %0, %smid;" : "=r"(ret) );
    return ret;
}
```

Source [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/468126/using-smid-compiling-a-ptx-/).

Comment: Thank you. I've seen that, I don't know where to put that exactly?

Comment: It's a device function returning SM ID callable by any thread using `get_smid()`. Treat it like a C function being called from inside your GPU kernel by threads.

Comment: Yes, but - having called it, where do I put the value? If it's in global memory - that has a lot of impact on the SM block assignment I'm trying to profile; and the same goes for printf()ing.

Comment: I guessed "that" in the first comment refers to the function definition. I think it's really up to the programmer's decision based on the application requested resources where to put the returned value so as to avoid affecting original CUDA application behavior; if this is what she/he meant.